# How to auto complete in an iPython notebook while on ipdb?

Tags: ipython, jupyter, ipython-magic

I am running some cell in an iPython notebook.
I used the %%debug command in the head of the cell.
Now, when i am on ipdb prompt and i hit the ctrl+space or tab,
auto complete can't seem to be working.

How to use auto complete?

Comment: There is no tab completion in the debugger when using any of the Jupyter frontends. Because of the design, there is not currently an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Install pyreadline:

```
pip install pyreadline
```

Open jupyter notebook & run the following in one the cell:

```
%config IPCompleter.greedy=True
```

Whenever you want to do autocomplete, just press TAB.

Works for me !!!

Comment: What operating system, etc. were you using? With firefox on OSX this doesn't work for me. The tab key just moves me into the next jupyter window. Any suggestions? Cheers.

Comment: same on windows 10

Comment: Hey - i'm facing same situation on OSX, firefox. Did you solve yours?